# How to create a differentiated marker class hierarchy

Tags: java, architecture, marker-interfaces

I have a case where I have a base interface (`X`), an updatable interface (`updatableX`), and a nonUpdatableInterface (`frozenX`).

`frozenX` implementations are expected to implement hashCode() and equals() methods so as to be suitable for use in hash maps and similar collections.
`frozenX` may be a marker interface.

`updatableX` implementations will not explicitly implement hashCode() or equals() as the values necessary to distinguish one X from another are the values that are updatable in `updatableX`.

`X` has all the other common methods.

Is it possible to define `X`, `updatableX` and `frozenX` is such a way as to ensure that there are no implementations `Y` such that `Y` implements both `updatableX` and `frozenX`?